# Ubuntu SSO - Hotmail as preferred address?

Tags: email, single-sign-on

To fetch my Ubuntu SSO-account with my existing Ubuntuforums account, I have to change my preferred email address in SSO. My registered email in Ubuntuforums is an old hotmail-account, which is also registered in Launchpad. When I try to set this email as preferred in SSO, it doesn't appear in the list, although i get a message, that it is already linked to the account.

Are hotmail-accounts not accepted in SSO? How to tell SSO to list my launchpad-account?

Comment: Please look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164051 which is accessible even without signing in. It may have some hints for you.

Comment: Another way is to just make a totally new account, sign in, and then post about your problem. One of the mods will ask you to PM certain details and will work with you to get your original account functional.